# Boundedness of the Hermite functions.

Tags: real-analysis, hermite-polynomials

Is it true that Hermite’s functions are bounded for any $n\in\mathbb{N_0},x\in \mathbb{R}?$ If it's true, how to prove it??

Answer (score 0):

Of course they are not. Polynomials never are. This is because as the argument (say $x$) gets large, the main term dominates all other terms (in the sense that it is a multiple of at least $x$ of any other term), so on letting $x \to \infty$ the polynomial will converge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ according to the sign of the main term.

For the physicist's Hermite functions, please see the comments.

Comment: Correct answer - but please don't say "converges to $\infty$". Just plain "unbouded" does the job.

Comment: Well, actually, if one imposes the topology given by the usual two-point compactification, convergence is a perfectly accurate term.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions
I'm not talking about polynomials

Comment: In this case, you may use that dividing by $e^{-x^2/2}$ causes the function to converge to zero as $x \to \infty$, since the exponential (let alone of a square) converges to infinity faster than any polynomial (in order to see this, use the series expansion, where you get exponents of arbitrary magnitude). So they are in fact bounded, albeit only on the real line; in the complex plane, Liouville's theorem implies that they are unbounded.

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous True if you impose that topology but then you should say so since the usage isn't standard.

Comment: @ИванПетров: In the notations of the Wikipedia page, are you asking if $\exists M\ge 0, \forall n, \forall x, |\psi_n(x)|\le M$ is true? I think this is false, but would have to think about a proof.

Comment: yes, that's what i asked

Comment: @ИванПетров: What I said is wrong. In fact there is such a bound by Harald Cramer, see the wikipedia page you linked to.